# Trouble with divs?

Tags: html, css

Okay, I'm very new to CSS and only minimally familiar with HTML so I'm still kind of fumbling around with both of them. I'm building a practice site and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here. My goal is to have the image box to the left of the header and paragraph, but have the title on the same line as the top of the image. Here's what I have:

```html
<img src="" />
<div class="bios">
  <h4>First Last</h4>
  <p>This is my bio</p>
</div>
```

Paired with this CSS:

```
        .bios {
          height: 100px;
          width: auto;
          display: inline;
          background-color: #a78ffc;
          clear: left;
          display: inline;
          /** top, right, bottom, left **/
          margin: 1px 1px 1px 10px;
          /** top, right, bottom, left **/
          padding: 1px 1px 1px 10px
        }

        img {
           height: 100px;
           width: 100px;
           float: left;
           clear: left;
           display: inline;
         }
```

I added the background color to really see what's going on in the preview and I'm more confused than ever. This is how it's displaying:

http://i1126.photobucket.com/albums/l618/spenciecakes/Screen%20Shot%202016-05-13%20at%2010.41.45%20AM_zps50dajzko.png

**EDIT**
Okay, I've added the additional code as requested and I've added the display: inline to both elements but honestly it all appears the same..

Comment: You should put your code in JSfiddle, it will be easier to work with that way

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Just tried it out and I'm not sure how it's easier to work with? I'm using Coda to write this site. And it appears JSfiddle is similar to Coda - unless I'm missing something..

Comment: **"My goal is to have the image box to the left of the header and paragraph, but have the title"** where is all this stuff you are talking about?

Comment: I did forget to add the image and for that I am sorry. The header is the h4 and the paragraph is the p? Also I attached a link to an image to how it's displaying. I'm I just totally going about everything wrong?

Comment: Okay I've added the rest of the code now..

Comment: Thanks for wanting to mark this question as solved. To do that here, either make a self-answer below, or accept an existing answer. We prefer titles to be left as they are - thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `display: inline-block`.

```css
.inline {
  display: inline-block;
}

.title {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="inline">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
  </div>
  <div class="inline">
    <div class="title">Item 1</div>
    <p>Item 1 description</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <div class="inline">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
  </div>
  <div class="inline">
    <div class="title">Item 2</div>
    <p>Item 2 description</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't solve your problem with only the code you provided (what's the code for the images?), but I can tell you what's wrong with the current code. First, in order for the `width` and `height` property to work, the `display` property needs to be set to either `inline-block` or `block`.

Secondly, the `float` property does *not* have a value `center`. It can only take the values `left` and `right` (you need to the first one in this case).

Answer (score 1):

The negative margin trick works like a charm (Explanation in code comments)

```css
.bio {
  overflow: hidden; /* Prevent negative margin from leaking out */
}

.bio-inner {
  overflow: hidden; /* Clearfix */
  margin-left: -1em; /* A) Remove spacing between items when they are against the left side (Must be negative B) */
}

.bio-thumbnail {
  height: 3em;
  width: auto;
  background-color: #a78ffc;
}

.bio-thumbnail,
.bio-info {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 1em; /* B) Add spacing between items (Must be positive A) */
}

.bio-info-heading {
  margin: 0em; /* Just removing default margins */
}

.bio-info-text {
  margin-top: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="bio">
  <div class="bio-inner">
    <img class="bio-thumbnail" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bI1Y.jpg">
    <div class="bio-info">
      <h4 class="bio-info-heading">First Last</h4>
      <p class="bio-info-text">This is my bio</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This, I have found, works best in cases where screens may be too small to fit the image and text side-by-side.